# Filling data in one column if there are matching values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF with parent/child items and I need to associate a time for the parent to all the children items.  The time is only listed when the parent matches the child and I need that time to populate on all the children.

This is a simple example.

```
data = {

     'Parent' : ['a123', 'a123', 'a123', 'a123', 'a234', 'a234', 'a234', 'a234'],
     'Child' : ['a123', 'a1231', 'a1232', 'a1233', 'a2341', 'a234', 'a2342', 'a2343'],
     'Time' : [51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0],
}
```

The expected results are:

```
results= {

     'Parent' : ['a123', 'a123', 'a123', 'a123', 'a234', 'a234', 'a234', 'a234'],
     'Child' : ['a123', 'a1231', 'a1232', 'a1233', 'a2341', 'a234', 'a2342', 'a2343'],
     'Time' : [51, 51, 51, 51, 39, 39, 39, 39],
}
```

Seems like it should be easy, but I can't wrap my head around where to start.

Comment: use .loc[] to filter to where they don't match, and replace the 0s in the Time column with np.nan, then use pandas .interpolate() (look up which settings to have) or .ffill()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If time is positive for the parent, or null, you can use a simple [`groupby.transform('max')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Time'] = df.groupby('Parent')['Time'].transform('max')
```

Else, you can use:

```
df['Time'] = (df['Time']
 .where(df['Parent'].eq(df['Child']))
 .groupby(df['Parent']).transform('first')
 .convert_dtypes()
)
```

Output:

```
  Parent  Child  Time
0   a123   a123    51
1   a123  a1231    51
2   a123  a1232    51
3   a123  a1233    51
4   a234  a2341    39
5   a234   a234    39
6   a234  a2342    39
7   a234  a2343    39
```